# How is the best way to say about hidden money?

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. you've got money stashed
> 2. you are the money hidden

How is the best way to say about hidden money

Comment: Make the effort to google such expressions yourself first. You'll find numerous references on the internet.  https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stash+away

Comment: The first one is grammatically correct and makes sense; the second one is "word salad" and makes no sense.

Comment: I am the money hidden? Me, some internet rando posting on ELL? Surely you don't mean that.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are very good, but "You've got money stashed" is better.

"You are" is generally an indication of a person's components (The items making them) or a person's qualities.  For example.

```
You are a carbon based life form.
You are rich.
```

People aren't money, so "you are the money" is always wrong in the plain sense of expression, no matter how you modify the money (stashed, lost, etc).  With this understanding, if the person is not speaking literally, this wording might make sense in some contexts.

The reason "You've got money stashed" is wrong is because the contraction "You've" expands to

```
You have got money stashed.
```

Which now uses two verbs (have and got) which both express possession.  It would be better to say

```
You have money stashed.
```